# C : Printing big numbers

Tags: c, printf

Take the following :

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    unsigned long long verybig = 285212672;

    printf("Without variable : %llu\n", 285212672);
    printf("With variable    : %llu", verybig);
}
```

This is the output of the above program :

```
Without variable : 18035667472744448
With variable    : 285212672
```

---

As you can see from the above, when `printf` is passed the number as a constant, it prints some huge incorrect number, but when the value is first stored in a variable, `printf` prints the correct number.

What is the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try `285212672ULL`; if you write it without suffixes, you'll find the compiler treats it as a regular integer. The reason it's working in a variable is because the integer is being cast up to an `unsigned long long` in the assignment, so that the value passed to `printf()` is the right type.

And before you ask, no, the compiler probably *isn't* smart enough to figure it out from the `"%llu`" in the `printf()` format string. That's a different level of abstraction. The compiler is responsible for the language syntax, `printf()` semantics are not part of the *syntax*, it's a runtime library function (no different really from your own functions except that it's included in the standard).

Consider the following code for a 32-bit int and 64-bit unsigned long long system:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    printf ("%llu\n",1,2);
    printf ("%llu\n",1ULL,2);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
8589934593
1
```

In the first case, the two 32-bit integers 1 and 2 are pushed on the stack and `printf()` interprets that as a single 64-bit ULL value, 2 x 2<sup>32</sup> + 1. The `2` argument is being inadvertently included in the ULL value.

In the second, you actually push the 64-bit 1-value and a superfluous 32-bit integer `2`, which is ignored.

Note that this "getting out of step" between your format string and your actual arguments is a bad idea. Something like:

```
printf ("%llu %s %d\n", 0, "hello", 0);
```

is likely to crash because the 32-bit `"hello"` pointer will be consumed by the `%llu` and `%s` will try to de-reference the final `0` argument. The following "picture" illustrates this (let's assume that cells are 32-bits and that the "hello" string is stored at 0xbf000000.

```
What you pass     Stack frames     What printf() uses
                 +------------+
0                | 0          | \
                 +------------+  > 64-bit value for %llu.
"hello"          | 0xbf000000 | /
                 +------------+
0                | 0          |    value for %s (likely core dump here).
                 +------------+
                 | ?          |    value for %d (could be anything).
                 +------------+
```

Comment: but i think compiler is smart enough to figure out %u in printf format spec, try printf("%d %u",~0,~0).. both will print values as expected..

Comment: No - those data types are the same size - it's printf() figuring that out - try %d with 'a'.

Comment: Pax: That's fine too, character literals are integer constants.

Comment: Right you are @caf, but the compiler is *still* not looking inside printf arguments. And it shouldn't since that's a different abstraction level (language vs. runtime library). I've updated the answer with more info.

Comment: In the code you use 1 and 2, but in the text you use 0 and 1 :)

Comment: Thanks, @litb, fixed. I originally had 0/1 but the behavior seemed a little ambiguous, which is why I changed [parts of] it.

Answer (score 5):

It's worth pointing out that some compilers give a useful warning for this case - for example, this is what GCC says about your code:

```
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:6: warning: format ‘%llu’ expects type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

Comment: Yet another reason not to ignore compilation *warnings*.

Answer (score 3):

`285212672` is an `int` value. `printf` expects an `unsigned long long` and you're passing it an `int`. Consequently, it'll take more bytes off the stack than you passed a real value and prints garbage. When you put it in an `unsigned long long` variable before passing it to the function, it'll be promoted to `unsigned long long` in the assignment line and you pass that value to `printf` which works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Datatype is simply a way of interpreting contents of a memory location.
in first case the constant value is stored in read only memory location as an int, the printf tries to interpret this address as 8 byte location as it is instructed that the value stored is long long in process of which it prints garbage value.
In the second case printf tries to interpret a long long value as 8 bytes and it prints what is expected.