# Facing problem with finding cube of large numbers

Tags: c

I have these 20 numbers

```
409,29,657,523,1481,447,904,312,110,1207,55,284,65,232,102,206,218,565,731,34
```

And they are the masses, I need to find average of $m^{3}$. but it is giving me the wrong answer. when I am adding them after some limit the sum go down. So I was trying to print the sum after each cube is added as `mmmsum = mmmsum +m*m*m;`

First I tried with just int data type (`%d`) and observed the sum going down, then assuming it may be due to limitations of the range I tried unsigned int then also I faced the same problem, so I tried unsigned long int same problem but at a higher sum only, then I tried unsigned long long, this time  the sum was coming more than expected at one point and after two sums it again goes down

```
    int main()
    {
            int m[] ={409,29,657,523,1481,447,904,312,110,1207,55,284,65,232,102,206,218,565,731,34};
            int mmmsum=0;

            for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
            {
                mmmsum = mmmsum + m[i]*m[i]*m[i];
                printf("\n %d",mmmsum);
            }

            return 0;
    }
```

Now if I use pow function to calculate the cube and unsigned long int (%lu) data type it is coming right. why is it not working for just m*m*m

the code I have shown above is the one I wrote for decoding: I am posting piece of original code, actually the array a is not there in real problem

```
    unsigned long long m_av,mm_av,mmm_av;
    ........
    //======= for M, MM, MMM =============
    m_av=0;mm_av=0;mmm_av=0;
    cluster = head;
    while(cluster)
    {
        l = cluster->label;
        m = L2[l];
        m_av    = m_av  + m;
        mm_av   = mm_av + m*m;
        mmm_av  = mmm_av+ pow(m,3);

        cluster = cluster->next_L;
    }
    m_av = m_av/Tnc;
    mm_av = mm_av/Tnc;
    mmm_av = mmm_av/Tnc;

    //===================================
fprintf(fp,"%lu\t%lf\t%d\t%llu\t%llu\t%llu etc.....\n",t_step,E,Tnc,m_av,mm_av,mmm_av,m_max,etc.....);
```

and in a simulation where I had 100,000 particles in total somewhere in between I was getting out put as below for this code

```
373926  0.225469    6   25000   48820678    109937352837987 . . .   
392623  0.225469    6   25000   48820678    109937352837987 . . .   
412254  0.205942    4   37500   194892454   179871291607140 . . .   
432867  0.205942    4   37500   194892454   179871291607140 . . .   
454510  0.205942    4   37500   194892454   179871291607140 . . . 
477235  0.020043    3   50000   6148914690883261936 664306051917360 . . 
501097  0.020043    3   50000   6148914690883261936 664306051917360 . .
526152  0.020043    3   50000   6148914690883261936 664306051917360 . .
552459  0.020043    3   50000   6148914690883261936 664306051917360 . .
580082  0.020043    3   50000   6148914690883261936 664306051917360 . .
609087  0.020043    3   50000   6148914690883261936 664306051917360 . .
639541  0.002030    2   75000   702942377   1247147318025000 . . .  
671518  0.002030    2   75000   702942377   1247147318025000 . . .  
705094  0.002030    2   75000   702942377   1247147318025000 . . .  
740348  0.002030    2   75000   702942377   1247147318025000 . . .
```

I think this has some relation with this question-> [C : Printing big numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385818/c-printing-big-numbers)

Comment: What is `m` in your provided code?

Comment: Your int variable overflows. Check the explanation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: use `unsigned long` instead of `int`. The format specifier is not the only thing you need to change.

Comment: @kuro I imagine the array might have been `m` and not `a`.

Comment: I assume the `int a[] = ...` should be `int m[] =...`

Comment: `for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(m)/sizeof(*m); ++i)` is safer (you don't need to adjust the loop if you change size of the array); be aware, though, that this doesn't work if you have dynamic arrays (`int* m = malloc(...);`) or the array decayed to pointer (e. g. because of having been passed to function).

Comment: Why are you using integers (of any size) for a physical quantity like mass in the first place?

Comment: `double` would be a good choice here, to contain the range and because the average is unlikely to be an integer.

Comment: I have tried int , unsigned int,unsigned long , unsigned long long as mentioned in the question. The problem faced are also explained, how can I send screenshots here. I can show them. Or someone just run it

Comment: Using only power function I got the right answer, and also I had to use atleast unsigned long. just multiplying as m*m*m was giving negative nembers after a value, unsigned int and unsigned long int was giving a decrement during the sum which is supposed only to go up. And finally using unsigned long long gave me a 20 digit large number in between where the sum was actually expected to be some 13/14 digits.. and the sum value printed continuing that was all wrong too.

Comment: @WeatherVane since numbers are coming in orders of $10^{15+}$ I think inter is enough in my case

Comment: @Aconcagua this array is actually not relevant. this values I extracted from the program during decoding to see where it goes wrong

Comment: @4386427, thanks and I think Aconcagua had corrected it

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Soryy I was uncareful. but I am sure I tried it right way also

Comment: This doesn't shed any light on my question. Why integers? Do you expect everything to be made of a whole number of kilograms, or grams, or whatever? If these numbers are not physical masses then you might need to use integers, but then `pow` is not appropriate.

Comment: Even if the weights are integers, the average is unlikely to be.

Comment: @n.m. oh now I understand pow( ) was expecting double input but I am giving integer input, and that may be causing issues as  Aconcagua mentioned

Comment: @WeatherVane: yes average will be having some numbers after decimal also. but in my problem mass is growing with time as t^{n}. so we are plotting it in a log scale , and the tics in axes are 10,100,1000,10000,100000, etc..  so in that reference even $12.54*10^{14}$ is enough for me, instead of some 1254154758876542.254879

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1481 * 1481 * 1481 = 3 248 367 641, which doesn't fit into `signed int` (32 bit provided, that's not necessarily the case), which has a maximum value of 2 147 483 647, so overflow occurs (that's undefined behaviour for *signed* integral types!).

> I have tried unsigned int, unsigned long and unsigned long long.

All of these should be large enough (with 32-bit, giving a range up to and including 4 294 967 295). Actually, the types from `<stdint.h>` (e. g. `uint64_t`) are preferable, as they come with guaranteed bit-width.

In any case, question is: *Where* have you tried that? Changing the underlying type of the *array* to these larger types will eliminate the problem immediately (provided you change the type of `mmmsum`, too, of course).

If you want or need (for whatever reason) to retain the `int` array, then you need to cast your operands to the larger type, otherwise `m * m * m` will still be calculated in (too small) `int`. So:

```
uint64_t mmmsum = 0;
// ...
    mmmsum += static_cast<uint64_t>(m[i]) * m[i] * m[i];
```

Casting only the first argument suffices, as the other arguments then will be promoted (converted) implicitly.

Using `pow` does something very similar: As function parameters are of type double, the `int` values are converted, too, *before* calculation, and double is large enough to hold the values in question. However, calculations in double can introduce rounding errors, with `pow` even if you use integral values. Sometimes the result gets (minimally) smaller than actual value, then when casting back to integral you get a bad value (too little by one). If working with integral values only, as in given case, adding 0.5 before casting back solves the issue already...

Side note on signed/unsigned: Don't decide for one bit of range to have signed or unsigned – if you need more range, switch to next larger data type. Decision about using signed or unsigned should only be made of negative values being meaningful or meaningless (apparently the latter in your case).

Comment: I have already mentioned that I have tried unsigned int, unsigned long and unsigned long long. Please somebody run this code then you will understand.

Comment: @fahd I see, apparently you did not try at the right place, though – adjusted the answer...

Comment: @fahd Very first question I'd ask now: Are negative masses meaningful? If not, I'd change the type of L2[l] to unsigned (maybe `uint32_t` to get guaranteed bit width even for mass itself?). Then if you get such close to maximum even of 32-bit unsigned, I'd switch to `uint64_t` for sum: `uint64_t m_av = 0, mm_av = 0, mmm_av = 0;`. `m` seems to be only relevant inside the loop, so declare it only there (always keep scope of variables as local as possible)!. Then you'd have: `uint64_t m = L2[l];` From now on, calculations are safe even for cube: `mmm_av += m * m * m;`.

Comment: If you insist on using `pow`, which I would *not* recommend, then prefer `mmm_av += pow(m, 3) + 0.5;` to avoid rounding errors as mentioned already.

Comment: Side note: Mathematically, `log(x^y) == y*log(x)`; this can be used for efficient calculation of general powers: `x^y = exp(y*log(x))`, and this is where rounding errors can occur even for integral values...

Comment: oh.. so the power function was expecting double, and it i making trouble, and adding this 0.5 will solveit, let me try it. But see now I have reduced my question to one problem, I am using unsigned long long int to print them, which is the maximum possible and I am getting the results as shown there

Comment: okay I think I should spend time to understand what you have said about uint64_t, thanks. but the mass itself can go only upto few lacks even one lack particles are taking too much time. And about L2[ ], is it necessary to change type of L2

Comment: can you have  look at this question please.. I couldn't match it with problem I am facing, But I think it is related (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385818/c-printing-big-numbers)

Comment: @fahd Related – your problem here and problem there are both related to size of integrals. But that's it already. What happened in your case was signed integer overflow. According to standard, that's undefined behaviour. Usually, the multiplication is just executed, but results can be truncated or even wrap around (if most significant bit gets set, the result will be a negative value even if both operands have been positive!). In any case, the result is invalid.

Comment: Problem there is that you actually use an `int` constant, but lie to the implementation telling it *was* a larger type (`%llu` -> `unsigned long long`). What happens there now is that the first four (usually, at least, can differ) bytes of the `int` on stack will be used and additionally four more other bytes, treating all like one huge number. However, these other four bytes might contain any garbage, so you might get some totally unrelated output (only on LE machine and these four bytes *by accident* all being zero you'd get desired result).

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think now it is solved, I removed pow( ), using unsigned long long and also casting L2[l] to the same